# What type of architecture style does the MEAN stack most resemble?

Tags: architecture, development-process, software

What type of software architecture style does the MEAN stack most resemble?

I am thinking Client/ Server because of the way messages are communicated between the different modules in both.

However, I'm not confident and would like some other people's opinion.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It depends what you build using those tools.

Answer (score 2):

The MEAN stack is not, itself, an architecture.  It's just a handful of tools that work pretty well together for building web applications.  "Web Application" probably comes closest, but there's a lot of detail you can go down to determine the *actual* architecture.

That said, you will find a number of application frameworks which use the MEAN stack (e.g. MEAN.io, MeanJS) which in turn implement a software architecture of their choice.

One could argue that it defaults to *at least* a 3 tiered architecture, because it implies that you have a DB (Mongo), an application server (Express & Node), and a client app (Angular).  But that's pretty thin, frankly, because you can still arrange things very differently even if you assume those four basic building blocks.